# A linear algebra problem. I write an answer, but I don't know it's right or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:
Let $A, B \in M_{n\times m}(F)$, show that $$rank (A+2B) \leq rank(A) + rank(B)$$
My answer:
I recognize $A, B$ as linear transformation. And $rank(A), rank(B)$ are the dimension of the image of two vector spaces respectively .
$$rank(A+2B) = dim(Im(A+2B)) = dim(ImA + 2ImB) = dim(ImA) + dim(Im2B) - dim(Im(A) \cap Im(2B)) \\ 
\leq dim(ImA) + dim(Im2B) = dim(ImA) + dim(ImB) = rank(A) + rank(B)$$
Did it right or not ?
Thanks.

Comment: why would $dim(ImA) + dim(Im2B) = dim(ImA) + dim(ImB)$ hold?

Comment: Why $Im(A+2B)=Im(A)+2Im(B)$? Take any $A$ and $B=-1/2*A$

Comment: Hint: $\text{rank}(A+2B)\leq \text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(2B)$ and $\text{rank}(2B) = \text{rank}(B)$.

Comment: [Here's a link to wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties)

Comment: $A, B$ are linear transformation, so $$(A+B)(x) = A(x) + B(y), B(\alpha * x) = \alpha * B(x)$$. I utilize this lemma.